# VBA Run-time error 1004 whe using .Cells() to copy from one sheet and paste in another

Tags: excel, vba, cell

If you could help me solve this problem with my code it would be much appreciated. I am receiving the 1004 error Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when I run the final line here but the line above that has been commented out works? LC is 6 as this shows up when I am in breakmode.

```
Public Sub Get_Table()
Dim LR As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim TD As Worksheet
Dim HTD As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Table"
Set TD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")
Set HTD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hedge Table Data")
'Find out the dimensions of the data that we have
LR = HTD.Cells(HTD.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LC = HTD.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column



With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
    .Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.Value = "Candidate Group"
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
    'Notes: -Could format with the bold stuff etc. At the end
    
    For I = 2 To LR
        .Cells(I + 1, 1).Value = I - 2
    Next I
    'We have the number of rows filled
    'Now we look at the columns to set up the table.
    .Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, LC - 1)).Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.Value = "Candidate Hedges"
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    For I = 2 To LC - 1
        .Cells(2, I).Value = I - 1
    Next I
    .Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF('Hedge Table Data'!R[-1]C[1]<>"""",'Hedge Table Data'!R1C[1],"""")"
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, LC - 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, LC - 1)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(LR + 1, LC - 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    'New VaR column
    .Range(Cells(1, LC), Cells(2, LC)).Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.Value = "New VaR"
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
End With


'This works: HTD.Range(HTD.Cells(2, 1), HTD.Cells(LR, 1)).Copy Destination:=TD.Range("F3")
HTD.Range(HTD.Cells(2, 1), HTD.Cells(LR, 1)).Copy Destination:=TD.Range(Cells(3, 8))


End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `TD.Range(Cells(3, 8))` with `TD.Cells(3, 8)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself by writing:

```
HTD.Range(HTD.Cells(2, 1), HTD.Cells(LR, 1)).Copy Destination:=TD.Cells(3, 8)
```

There is no range necessary when referring to one cell with `.Cells()`